# uso de mapa de bits en c++

Tags: c++

Practicaba el uso de mapa de bits en C++ me es muy interesante, tengo varias dudas sobre esto  mi objetivo es entender mas a fondo expresamente al mapa de bits en C++:

¿Por qué no puedo tratar un mapa de bits directamente con cin? digamos por ejemplo `int x : 4; cin>>x;`, por lo que voy entendiendo puedo ajustar en bytes lo que vaya a guardar en un mapa de bits digamos una `string` u otro tipo de dato que sea arbitrario ya que el mapa de bits es un buen artificio para lograr esto ¿estoy en lo correcto en este aspecto?.

¿Qué limites tiene el uso del mapa de bits además de la no portabilidad de código?, ¿Qué más potencial se le puede sacar a esto?, en sus experiencias ¿Qué trucos por así decirlo me enseñarían XD con el mapa de bits? ¿Cómo se usaría un campo sin identificador? ejemplo: `int : 4;`

El siguiente codigo es una de las practicas que he hecho:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
struct fecha{
    unsigned short dia : 16;
    unsigned short mes : 16;
    unsigned short annio : 16;
};

void declaracion();
void mostar(fecha x);
int main()
{
    declaracion();
    return 0;
}

void mostrar(struct fecha x)
{
    std::string meses[] = {"enero","febrero","marzo", "abril","mayo","junio","julio","agosto","septiempre","octubre","diciembre"};  
    std::cout<<"fecha "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"dia : "<<x.dia<<" mes : "<<(meses[x.mes-1])<<" anio : "<<(x.annio+1960)<<std::endl;
    
}
void declaracion()
{
    fecha x;
    x.dia = 31;
    x.mes = 12;
    x.annio = 60;
    mostrar(x);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Practicaba el uso de mapa de bits

Lo que estás usando NO SON mapas de bits. Son [**campos de bit**](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) (*bitfields* en inglés).

---

> ¿Por qué no puedo tratar un mapa de bits directamente con cin? digamos por ejemplo `int x : 4; cin>>x;`.

Es mentira, sí se puede:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    int x : 4;
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    s.x = 5;
    std::cout << s.x << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYwxCsMwEARr3ysWUjgpElIkjSTnE27TCFkEgX020gkMxm9XpGpnd2Ddtt3dbPlXyiWwm/PkYcKaJHq7fIgqZCcY6aAusGCHwkvTqYlaXWzg663JEUlTlx47BrwbyaSUW7PAGLS5Rv/lvqroJUfGs96U8gc)</kbd>.

Lo que no puedes hacer es declarar un campo de bits fuera de un objeto, porque como su nombre indica son campos y en consecuencia, no pueden ir por libre.

---

> por lo que voy entendiendo puedo ajustar en bytes lo que vaya a guardar en un mapa de bits digamos una `string` u otro tipo de dato que sea arbitrario ya que el mapa de bits es un buen artificio para lograr esto ¿estoy en lo correcto en este aspecto?.

Lo has entendido mal. Para empezar no ajustas en bytes si no en bits, para seguir no puedes hacer un campo de bits de un tipo que no sea [integral](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) (entero) por lo que el `std::string` queda descartado y para acabar el tipo de dato no puede ser arbitrario si no (como se ha dicho) integral.

Los **campos** (que no mapa) de bits no son un artificio para guardar `string`, son una utilidad del lenguaje para ajustar el tamaño (en bits) de **campos** de objetos.

---

> ¿Qué limites tiene el uso del mapa de bits además de la no portabilidad de código?

No puedes ajustar el tamaño para que sea mayor al del tipo declarado:

```
struct S
{
    int x : 64; // 'int' es máximo de 32 bits, así que se quedará con 32 bits no con 64.
};
```

No puedes usar tamaños negativos:

```
struct S
{
    int x : -4; // Error
};
```

No puedes usar tamaño cero:

```
struct S
{
    int x : 0; // Error
};
```

El tamaño total no tiene por qué coincidir con el tamaño definido:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    int x : 24;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(S) * 8 << '\n'; // Muestra 32, no muestra 24
}
```

---

> ¿Qué más potencial se le puede sacar a esto?

Partiendo del punto en que no has entendido ni el concepto ni el uso de los **campos** de bits, cualquier potencial que hayas imaginado es incorrecto. Los **campos** de bits pueden ser útiles para tratar con datos que empaquetan información en bits concretos, como (por ejemplo) los bloques de datos del [formato GIF](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt) o para definir un color en formato [RGB565](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_color), por poner ejemplos concretos:

```
struct RGB565
{
    unsigned r : 5;
    unsigned g : 6;
    unsigned b : 5;
};
```

---

> ¿Qué trucos por así decirlo me enseñarían XD con el mapa de bits?

No hay trucos, se usa para lo que se usa. Puedo enseñarte un truco para abrir una botella de cerveza con un destornillador pero eso no hace que un destornillador sea un abridor.

[image]

---

> ¿Cómo se usaría un campo sin identificador? ejemplo: `int : 4;`

Un campo sin identificador se usa para alinear la información dentro de un objeto, si no necesitas los datos en esa posición entonces tampoco necesitas darles nombre:

```
struct S
{
    int : 5; // Primeros cinco bits sin uso
    int valor : 27;
};
```

Comment: Como todas tus respuestas, muy buena respuesta!! Gracias

Comment: gracias excelente explicación como siempre